# OSX Server 10.6.7 + Apache2: Setting Up IP-Based Virtual Hosting

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, mac-osx-server, phusion-passenger, osx-snow-leopard

I've developed a small Rails app that I need to run on my local network. I got Apache2 and Phusion Passenger set up, and the app is running on the server at `http://myapp.dev`, but I am not sure how to set it up so that I can access the app from any computer on the network. I know that if I had it running on `rails server` with WebBrick, that I could reach the app from any computer by visiting `192.168.0.141:3000` (with `192.168.0.141` being my IP, of course). I want this type of functionality from my current setup.

Here's my VirtualHost configuration from my `httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.dev
    DocumentRoot "/webapps/myapp/public"
    <Directory "/webapps/myapp/public">
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's a screengrab of my Server Admin settings:

[image: Applications - Server - Server Admin]

Everything else is default - I just set this up yesterday, and I really don't know how to configure it all that well yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document root points to /var/www and not "/webapps/myapp/public". And you need to make decision - you will either manipulate the conf files directly or use Server Admin. You can't do both because it leads to a total mess.